# react native - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm exporting an external module of this library: https://github.com/GoIntegro/react-native-account-manager

Since the library is outdated and doesn't work beyond for > 0.47, I had to include this library as an external module.

Everything was working fine, but now suddenly upon calling `react-native upgrade`, I'm getting this error:

[image]

My settings.gradle contains this:

```
include ':react-native-account-manager'
project(':react-native-account-manager').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../external_modules/react-native-account-manager/android')
```

And this is in my app level build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':react-native-account-manager')
    ...
}
```

Anyone has any idea how am I supposed to fix this? Is there something wrong with the way I'm importing this library or is it something within the library that is outdated that I need to fix?

Comment: Maybe try cleaning the android build then re-link the module and re-build. => cd android && ./gradlew --info clean && cd .. && react-native link && react-native run-android

Comment: Already tried that. I think there's something wrong with the way this NativeModule has been linked, but I don't know what.

Comment: Damn, okay.... Which react and react-native version are you using? And where does it say that you cant use this library for versions beyond v0.47?

Comment: I'm using react 16.2.0 and react-native 0.53.3. You can see the pull request that didn't get approved by the author yet regarding the depreciation from v0.47.0 : https://github.com/GoIntegro/react-native-account-manager/pull/2

Comment: I have forked the project and fixed it, maybe instead of using it as "external module" just use my fork or do your own and install it directly this way. You can install my fork like this: ```yarn add https://github.com/BigPun86/react-native-account-manager.git``` i tested it and it works on my system (react native "0.53.0")